# How do a mock a superclass that is part of a library?

Tags: python, mocking, unit-testing

I have some code like the following in Python:

*library.py*:

```
class HasSideEffects(object):

    def __init__(self, kittens):
        print 'kittens cry'  # <- side effect

    def launch_nukes(self):
        print 'launching nukes'  # <- side effect
```

*my_code.py*:

```
from library import HasSideEffects


class UtilitySubclass(HasSideEffects):

    def party(self):
        self.launch_nukes()
        return 'confetti'  # I want to test that my confetti cannon will work


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = UtilitySubclass(1)  # oh no! crying kittens :(
    x.party()  # oh no! nukes!
```

I want to unit test that when I call `party` I will get `confetti`. However, I want to avoid all the side effects that are part of the library class I am subclassing. More specifically, I want to avoid these side effects in the unit tests, but the side effects are needed in the production code.

I cannot change the code in `library.py` because it's a library, and I did not write the code. Obviously I wouldn't want to maintained a forked version of a library just to facilitate a unit test.

I've been trying to mock the `HasSideEffects` superclass. I need to mock `__init__` and `launch_nukes` in the superclass so they no longer perform side effects. I've been having some trouble mocking the `__init__` method, apparently the Python `mock` library does not support it?

What's the best way to test that `party` return `confetti`, while avoiding side effects?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you was quite close to a solution:

> I've been trying to mock the HasSideEffects superclass. I need to mock **init** and launch_nukes in the superclass so they no longer perform side effects. I've been having some trouble mocking the **init** method, apparently the Python mock library does not support it?

[`unittest.mock` and legacy `mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) are designed exactly to do this kind of work. When you need to remove dependencies from library or resources mock it and replace by `patch` is powerful especially when you should play with legacy code that you cannot change.

In your case you need to patch either `__init__` method: to do it you must take in account two things

1. If the class is subclassed and you need patch it when build a subclass object you must patch `__init__` directly instead of class definition.
2. `__init__` method MUST return `None` and your mock too.

Now come back to your simple example: I changed it a little bit to make tests more explicit.

**library.py**

```
class HasSideEffects(object):

    def __init__(self, kittens):
        raise Exception('kittens cry')  # <- side effect


    def launch_nukes(self):
        raise Exception('launching nukes')  # <- side effect
```

**my_code.py**

```
from library import HasSideEffects

class UtilitySubclass(HasSideEffects):

    def party(self):
        self.launch_nukes()
        return 'confetti'  # I want to test that my confetti cannon will work
```

**test_my_code.py**

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, ANY
from my_code import UtilitySubclass


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_step_by_step(self):
        self.assertRaises(Exception, UtilitySubclass) #Normal implementation raise Exception
        #Pay attention to return_value MUST be None for all __init__ methods
        with patch("library.HasSideEffects.__init__", autospec=True, return_value=None) as mock_init:
            self.assertRaises(TypeError, UtilitySubclass) #Wrong argument: autospec=True let as to catch it
            us = UtilitySubclass("my kittens") #Ok now it works
            #Sanity check: __init__ call?
            mock_init.assert_called_with(ANY, "my kittens") #Use autospec=True inject self as first argument -> use Any to discard it
            #But launch_nukes() was still the original one and it will raise
            self.assertRaises(Exception, us.party)
            with patch("library.HasSideEffects.launch_nukes") as mock_launch_nukes:
                self.assertEqual("confetti",us.party())
                # Sanity check: launch_nukes() call?
                mock_launch_nukes.assert_called_with()

    @patch("library.HasSideEffects.launch_nukes")
    @patch("library.HasSideEffects.__init__", autospec=True, return_value=None)
    def test_all_in_one_by_decorator(self, mock_init, mock_launch_nukes):
        self.assertEqual("confetti",UtilitySubclass("again my kittens").party())
        mock_init.assert_called_with(ANY, "again my kittens")
        mock_launch_nukes.assert_called_with()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Note as the decorator version is neat and simple.

Comment: Is unittest.mock part of Python 3? I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: In Python 2.7 use `mock` instead of `unitest.mock`. You must get it from `pip` by `pip install mock`

Comment: @Buttons840 Sorry I forgot to tag your name... In Python 2.7 use `mock` instead of `unitest.mock`. You must get it from `pip` by `pip install mock`

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty tricky question to answer in general.  If the library class that you're mocking is simple enough, then you can provide your functionality as a *mixin*.

```
class UtilitySubclassMixin(object):
    def party(self):
        self.launch_nukes()
        return 'confetti'

class UtilitySubclass(library.HasSideEffects, UtilityClassMixin):
    """meaningful docstring."""
```

Now, for testing you just need to provide a subclass that has the interface that your UtililtySubclassMixin expects (e.g. something with a `launch_nukes` method).  This isn't ideal, but if you need to mock out a library method that has an `__init__` with side-effects it's about the best you can do.  If it's all non-magic methods that have side-effects, `unittest.mock` can be used to patch the methods on `library.HasSideEffects` directly.

And, FWIW, this is a very good reason why `__init__` methods should never have side effects :-).