# Why can't I patch multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, pytest, python-multiprocessing, python-unittest.mock, pytest-mock

So I have these files:

**transmitter.py**

```py
import multiprocessing as MP
from common import BaseWorker

class TxWorker(BaseWorker):
    ... code ...
```

**common.py**

```py
import multiprocessing as MP

class BaseWorker(MP.Process):
    ... code ...
```

Now I have this test file, written for pytest with pytest-mock plugin:

```py
from transmitter import TxWorker

class MockProcess:
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = name

    def canary():
        return "Mocked!"

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def mocked_process(module_mocker):
    module_mocker.patch(WHERE_TO_PATCH, MockProcess)
    yield

def test_case(mocked_process):
    tw = TxWorker()
    assert tw.canary() == "Mocked!"
```

I can't get this test to work.

I've tried setting `WHERE_TO_PATCH` to:

- `transmitter.MP.Process`
- `common.MP.Process`
- `multiprocessing.Process`

None of them works. I keep having the error `AttributeError: 'TxWorker' object has no attribute 'canary'`.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do a mock a superclass that is part of a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181867/how-do-a-mock-a-superclass-that-is-part-of-a-library)

Comment: Because you're using it as a superclass.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon so in essence: I cannot replace the class, I should hijack its `__init__` instead?

Comment: Or use the mixin approach in mgilson's answer, or do something else.

Comment: Yeah I was originally planning to isolate BaseWorker so it won't actually start in a separate process. The canary() was just to ensure that I've patched the correct `Process`. But thanks anyways for the tip!